# I am trying to create a table in HTML with 4 total columns and three total rows, including the header row, but my current code results in this

Tags: html, html-table

The 2 rows, aside from the header row, should each contain 2 cells that have semester 1 and semester 2, since there are two semesters in a year.

For example:
First Year
Semester 1: 15 credit hours
Semester 2: 15 credit hours

That is what I am trying to do for each column, yet my code does not come close to that result. I am very new to HTML, and am having trouble with other online resources. If there are any details I am leaving out, that is due to my own ignorance. I appreciate the help!

[image: Incorrect Table]

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>First Year</th>
<th>Second Year</th>
<th>Third Year</th>
<th>Fourth Year</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Semester 1: 15 credit hours</td>
<td>Semester 2: 15 credit horus</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Semester 1: 15 credit hours</td>
<td>Semester 2: 15 credit hours</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Semester 1: 15 credit hours</td>
<td>Semester 2: 15 credit hours</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Semester 1: 15 credit hours</td>
<td>Semester 2: 15 credit hours</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use colspan

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">First Year</th>
        <th colspan="2">Second Year</th>
        <th colspan="2">Third Year</th>
        <th colspan="2">Fourth Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Semester 1: 15 credit hours</td>
        <td>Semester 2: 15 credit horus</td>
        <td>Semester 1: 15 credit hours</td>
        <td>Semester 2: 15 credit hours</td>
        <td>Semester 1: 15 credit hours</td>
        <td>Semester 2: 15 credit hours</td>
        <td>Semester 1: 15 credit hours</td>
        <td>Semester 2: 15 credit hours</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I took out the bottom part and it worked great! Cheers!